# Can you enchant a plain +1 item to a +1 with property?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Can you enchant a plain +1 item to a +1 with property?

The `Enchant Magic Item` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=ritual&id=9)] says ... *Alternatively, you can use the ritual to upgrade a common, uncommon, or rare item to a more powerful version of the item that is 5 levels higher.*

Which I read as e.g. +1 sword to +2 sword, or +1 Flaming Sword to +2 Flaming Sword, but could you do +1 Sword to +1 Flaming Sword ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

What you have to do in this case is use `Disenchant Magic Item` get the residuum (at 20%/50%/100% (depending on rarity)) and then use `Enchant Magic Item` to put the enchantment you want on the item, paying the full cost.

You can only use it to upgrade the current enchantment.